# Linking Github repositories in one Org to different Azure Dev Ops projects

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-boards, github-app

I'm managing multiple repositories under one Github organizations. I would like to link these to different Azure Dev Ops projects, more or less like this:

- Github org1/repo1 --> ADO org1/project 1
- Github org1/repo2 --> ADO org2/project 2

The Azure Boards Github App seems to only allow repos in the same organization to be linked to one project. Is there a way to do what I want?

I have tried specifing repositories separately in the Azure Board configuration in the organization's Github Apps, but it seems to link all repos to only 1 project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document [Install the Azure Boards app for GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/install-github-app?view=azure-devops), it is not support to link repositories in one GitHub organization to   projects in different Azure DevOps organization.

> You can connect an Azure DevOps organization to multiple GitHub repositories if you're an administrator for those repositories. However, you shouldn't connect a GitHub repository to more than one Azure DevOps organization.